# Data from SQL Server table to Web API

Tags: ssis, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to use an Integration Services project in VS2012 to pull data from a database table and push it in JSON or XML format over HTTP to a Web server?  I haven't had luck searching the internet; the signal-to-noise ratio is way to low on my results.  I've tried looking into use the HTTP Connection Manager, but I've only seen examples of it being used in conjunction with a WSDL.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a [script component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137640.aspx) to do this?

Comment: No, but it did seem to me that this would be a common enough use case that it would be built-in.  I'm new to SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would try using the HttpWebRequest in a Script Component.

Here is a link to a blog post about sending JSON to a service: [Making a JSON service request using C#](http://blog.manglar.com/json-post-request/)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Mike.  Perhaps in the next version, this will be built-in somehow.  I'm new to integration services.  If I have an OLE DB Source going into a Script Component, can I add a member variable to the script component class (`public class ScriptMain : UserComponent`) and have that persist through the life of the package execution?  I need to make one Web API call for all rows with the same value for a specific column, so I was going to sort the data by that column, aggregate it in the variable, and when the value changes or `PostExecute` is called, make the Web API call.

Comment: Incidentally, it looks like you can't use a Nuget package in a Script Component unless the assemblies are in the GAC: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/81115518-2e27-4fe6-859d-3da1a56c4aec/ssis-script-component-c-and-nuget  We have some Nuget packages we use for our Web API calls in other C# projects.